# What is $C$ when $(X,Y)$ has pdf $C\exp(-\alpha \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2 \beta xy} )$ for $x,y\in \mathbb R$?

Tags: probability, integration, probability-distributions, multiple-integral

A probability vector $(X,Y)$ follows a distribution with PDF $$f(x,y)=C\exp(-\alpha \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2 \beta xy} )\quad -\infty \lt x,y \lt\infty$$

$\alpha, \beta, C$ are constants and  $\alpha \gt0, -1\lt\beta\lt1$

I need to express $C$ using $\alpha, \beta$.

---

I set $$I = \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } \displaystyle \int_{-\infty}^{ \infty } C\exp(-\alpha \sqrt{x^2+y^2+2 \beta xy} ) \,dx\,dy = 1$$

and but don't know how to tackle this integral. I first thought polar conversion  may be　a tool but could not deal with $2\beta xy$.

Comment: $$
\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }\int _{-\infty }^{\infty }e^{-\alpha  \sqrt{x^2+2 \beta  x y+y^2}}\ \mathsf dx\ \mathsf dy = \frac{2 \pi }{\alpha ^2 \sqrt{1-\beta ^2}}
$$

Comment: @Math1000 how did you get there?

Comment: Mathematica. I don't know how to compute that integral by hand, sorry.

Comment: @Math1000 Thank you how should I google to search this type of integral?

Comment: https://wolframalpha.com :)